# Convert Either[A, B] to Option[A] where Left becomes Some

Tags: scala, either, scala-option

I would like to convert an `Either[A, B]` to an option, such that if `Either` is `Left` it is `Some[A]`, and if it is `Right` it is `None`.

So far I've come up with

```scala
either.swap.map(Some(_)).getOrElse(None)
```

which is a bit of a mouthful.

and

```
either match { 
  case Left(value) => Some(value)
  case Right(_) => None
}
```

which is fine, but ideally I would like to know if there's a more idiomatic way using methods rather than an explicit match.

Comment: `either.swap.toOption` - [the **scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) is your friend.

Comment: Lovely, thanks! Now why couldn't I find that however much I searched on Google...

Comment: That is why I suggested the **scaldoc** google is pretty good to find complex problems not simple methods. My personal suggestion is always you need a method open the scaladoc and search there. _(applies to almost all libraries / langauges)_

Comment: Ok, thanks for that advice

Comment: By the way feel free to answer the question so I can accept it and people know not to bother answering. There's no option to close as answer no longer needed unfortunately.

Comment: Nah, I do not feel worth writing one line answers. BTW, other advice, next time you have a problem that you believe should be answered in one line or two or want a more realtime interaction I would recommend you to ask in the [scala **gitter** channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) IMHO StackOverflow should be used only when you believe your problem is big enough and you have already tried a couple of ways to solve the problem. _(big enough doesn't necessary means many lines of code, just complexity of the problem)_.

Comment: @MarioGalic I think you can't accept it for a couple of days if you do

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Apologies for copying your comment, but IMO it is useful enough to be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting Luis's comment to answer we have

```
either.swap.toOption
```

For example

```
val either: Either[String, Int] = Left("Boom")
either.toOption
either.swap.toOption
```

outputs

```
res0: Option[Int] = None
res1: Option[String] = Some(Boom)
```

where we note `either.toOption` returns `Option[Int]` whilst `either.swap.toOption` returns `Option[String]`.

<sub>Apologies for copying in Luis' comment, but IMO it is useful enough to be posted as an answer.</sub>